# react native - Cannot select button behind "transparentModal"

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

I use `transparentModal` for open a modal in react native.

- Stack Group 1: Contains App Screens
- Stack Group 2: using `transparentModal` for handling modal

The modal only occupies 2/3 of screen, and there are some button on the top which should be clickable. However, we cannot press these buttons.

Please take a look at the image below

[image]

If you have any idea, please let me know.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Transparent modals are just another screen (s. [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#transparent-modals)). Meaning that the background's screen is set to transparent, but the underlying screen is not pressable.

A possible solution is to move your buttons in a custom header component for your transparentModal screen (s. [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers#replacing-the-title-with-a-custom-component)).

Alternatively (but in your case that's seems not the right way to go), you can set `cardOverlayEnabled: true` to make the screen close if you tap on the background of your transparent modal screen.

Answer (score 0):

Bad news is that we cannot do it using `react-navigation`

Please take a look at this [link](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/4560)